# Moving the bulk of a recursive ray tracer function to the gpu, using DirectX12 not DirectX 12 DXR HLSL

Tags: hlsl, raytracing, directx12

So I'm wanting to generate images by ray tracing. I've done so, but the main ray function is recursive. I know one can make a non recursive function out of a recursive function using a stack, but is it possible to do in HLSL? I have the bulk of the function I'm using here:

```
color ray_color(
    const ray& r,
    const color& background,
    const hittable& world,
    const shared_ptr<hittable>& lights,
    int depth) {
    
hit_record rec;

// If we've exceeded the ray bounce limit, no more light is gathered.
if (depth <= 0)
    return color(0, 0, 0);

// If the ray hits nothing, return the background color.
if (!world.hit(r, 0.001, infinity, rec))
    return background;

scatter_record srec;
color emitted = rec.mat_ptr->emitted(r, rec, rec.u, rec.v, rec.p);

if (!rec.mat_ptr->scatter(r, rec, srec))
    return emitted;

if (srec.is_specular) {
    return srec.attenuation
        * ray_color(srec.specular_ray, background, world, lights, depth - 1);
}

auto light_ptr = make_shared<hittable_pdf>(lights, rec.p);
mixture_pdf p(light_ptr, srec.pdf_ptr);
ray scattered = ray(rec.p, p.generate(), r.time());
auto pdf_val = p.value(scattered.direction());

return emitted
    + srec.attenuation * rec.mat_ptr->scattering_pdf(r, rec, scattered)
    * ray_color(scattered, background, world, lights, depth - 1)
    / pdf_val;
}
```

Comment: I know this function is using many other classes, I’m not concerned about implementing this exact function, my main concern is implementing recursion in HLSL, so I want to know if there’s a way to implement a stack of function pointers in HLSL, or some other technique, so that I could have an algorithm that calls ray splits functioning as if it was recursive.

Comment: I'm thinking now about dropping the whole recursion idea and just iterate through rays using static variables of some sort, any ideas on this approach? What about ray splitting on a glass surface?

Answer (score 0):

So I was under the mistaken assumption that a ray needs to be generated recursively, also that it would need to keep track of branching. I understand now that I can just send a single ray out at a time and test for hits without recursion. The pdf, probability distribution function, fidgets with the ray to take other paths I'm pretty sure.